# Send only JSON error instead of html in node.js

Tags: node.js, json, express, error-handling

Whenever a user registers in the app with invalid details like phone-number or email I want to throw an error as **JSON object** but it is displaying the *html* in the postman response.

The register route:

```
exports.register = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    var isValidated = await userService.validateInDatabase(req);
    if (!isValidated)
      return res
        .status(409)
        .json({ error: "Phone number or email is already registered" });

    var user = await userService.create(req.body);
    var token = await sendVerification(user);
    return res.status(201).json({ user, token });
  } catch (e) {
    return res.status(400).json({ message: e.message });
  }
};
```

The validate function:

```
const validate = (schema) => (req, res, next) => {
  const validSchema = pick(schema, ["params", "query", "body"]);
  const object = pick(req, Object.keys(validSchema));
  const { value, error } = Joi.compile(validSchema)
    .prefs({ errors: { label: "key" }, abortEarly: false })
    .validate(object);

  if (error) {
    const errorMessage = error.details
      .map((details) => details.message)
      .join(", ");
    return next(new ApiError(httpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, errorMessage));
  }
  Object.assign(req, value);
  return next();
};
```

The API endpoint for user registration:

```
router
  .route("/register")
  .post(validate(userValidation.createUser), User.register);
```

The error:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Error</title>
</head>

<body>
    <pre>Error: &quot;phoneNumber&quot; length must be at least 10 characters long...</pre>
</body>

</html>
```

The apiError function:

```
class ApiError extends Error {
  constructor(statusCode, message, isOperational = true, stack = "") {
    super(message);
    this.statusCode = statusCode;
    this.isOperational = isOperational;
    if (stack) {
      this.stack = stack;
    } else {
      Error.captureStackTrace(this, this.constructor);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post code of ApiError function?

Comment: @DrashtiKheni question updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By passing an error to the `next` callback, it gets passed to Express's error handling middleware, which in turn will render an HTML error page.

If you want to return validation errors as JSON, return a response directly from `validate` instead:

```
// not this:
return next(new ApiError(httpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, errorMessage));

// but this:
return res.status(400).json({ message: errorMessage });
```

Alternatively, if you want to streamline error handling in your app overall, you can use a custom error handling middleware which could, for instance, always return a JSON response in case an `ApiError` was thrown:

```
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  if (err instanceof ApiError) {
    return res.status(err.statusCode).json({ message: err.message }) 
  }
  // pass the error to the default error handler
  return next(err);
});
```

Comment: Ok your solution works but what about error class that I have created. I want to simplify the error object

Comment: @JohnOliver see edit for a more generic error handling solution

Answer (score 2):

I had same issue. I moved middleware implementation line below the routes.

**Before**

```js
// middleware for error
app.use(errorMiddleWare);
app.use('/api/v1', products);
```

**After**

```js
app.use('/api/v1', products);
// middleware for error
app.use(errorMiddleWare);
```

Comment: This worked for me, had no idea, thanks!